# Using $AM \ge GM$ which is greater among $1+\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $2^{1/n}$.

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

From expansion I see that $1+\dfrac{1}{n} \ge2^{1/n}$.But can't solve it using $AM \ge GM$. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_{n-1}=1$ and $a_n=2$.

The sum of the $a_i$ is $n+1$, so the AM is $1+\frac{1}{n}$. The product of the $a_i$ is $2$, so the GM is $2^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{n+1}{n} \ge 2^{\frac{1}{n}}$

$\prod b_i=2$ and $\sum b_i=n+1$

Let $x^n-(n+1)x^{n-1}+ \dots a_1x+2=0$,

This is a polynomial which have $n$ roots such that product is $2$ and sum is $n+1$. The *possible* factorization can be

$(x-1)(x-1)(x-1) \underbrace \dots (x-1)(x-2)=0$

Now that you have roots you can use **AM-GM** as Andre Nicolas says.